# How can I ensure all Java threads die

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing a multithreaded Java program, which I will run from the command prompt. It's got both a gui (javafx) and a lot of background threads. If I hit Ctrl+C from the command prompt that I started the program with, it asks "Terminate Batch job? Y/N" and I hit Y and then I'm simply returned to the prompt. However - I am wondering if there by any chance might still be running any background threads that weren't terminated gracefully?

Comment: have a reference to them in an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "main" code and all the threads run in `JVM`. If you terminate JVM (as process) then everything running in it will be terminated as well.

More on "catching" `ctrl+c`: [Catching Ctrl+C in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611931/catching-ctrlc-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to "catch" or "intercept" Ctrl+C "event" from the command line, so your can't really tell if there are any unfinished threads and end them gracefully. (disappointing, I know).